# WARNING ITMS-90725:SDK Version Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.2 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later." please help me

Comment: Check what Xcode version you have. It looks like just a warning but you'll need to update your Xcode version before March 2019

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure you have the latest version of Xcode.**

If you do have **Xcode 10.1** this is just a reminder that all of your apps need to comply with these terms.

Also regardless of Xcode version if your app did archive/build successfully you have nothing to worry about at the moment.

EDIT: **Starting in March 2019, ALL APPS submitted to the AppStore must have the 12.1 SDK**